# Profiling shows long execution time in PropertiesEnhancer

Tags: java, playframework

Serializing around 4000 objects into JSON took around 4 seconds (3820ms to be exactly). While profiling why this takes so long I recognized that about 40% of the time (1535ms) is spent in

```
play.classloading.enhancers.PropertiesEnhancer$FieldAccessor.invokeReadProperty(Object, String, String, String)
```

and it takes about 1152ms to get the "getter" method through reflection.

Do you have any idea why this takes so long and how to work around it or optimize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflection is not a cheap operation. The method you mention makes it even worse: trying to get a method via reflection first, possible catching an exception and trying to get a field then. And the method does not do any attempt of caching results. If this is called very often it’s no surprise that it is eating a lot of CPU time.

Whether it is possible to work-around this without changing the library, I don’t know. The only context I have is that single method reference from you. That’s not enough.